# classList.toggle acts like classList.add

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why the `classList.toggle` I used acts like `classList.add`. When I click the list items that have dropdown menus, it just makes changes on the first click and nothing on the second click.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var hasSubmenu = query('.basic-dropdown-click').querySelectorAll('.has-submenu');

hasSubmenu.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {

    for(var i=0; i < this.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
      this.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove('clicked');
    }

    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
  })
})
```

```css
.basic-dropdown-click {
  display: table;
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li {
  width: 120px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:hover {
  background: #484848;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2), .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font: 0.9rem 'Roboto';
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2).clicked, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5).clicked {
  background: #484848;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2).clicked > ul, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5).clicked > ul {
  display: block;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #555;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:hover, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li:hover {
  background: #484848;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:not(:first-child), .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li a, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font: 0.9rem 'Roboto';
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 0.9rem 'Roboto';
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="basic-dropdown-click">
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu">Item 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <ul class="item-2-submenu">
          <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu">Item 5 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <ul class="item-5-submenu">
          <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You are going up from the clicked element to the parent, and then remove the class for _all_ children (which of course includes the originally clicked element). So `this` does not have the class `clicked` any more, and now you are trying to toggle it - so naturally it gets _added_.

Comment: So, should I use `e.target` instead?

Comment: No, you need to stop toggling the class (which is effectively what you are doing by _removing_ it from the element which currently has it set) before you toggle the class. Trivial way to do that - check if the child _is_ the element that was clicked on, before you remove the class - `if(this.parentNode.children[i] != this) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one trivial solution ..

your problem is you are removing 'clicked' class from everyone and then trying to toggle it.. which ends up adding it again.. hence behaviour like 'add'

so i have just checked if there was already 'clicked' class using a variable 'has'

i have added comments in the code

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var hasSubmenu = query('.basic-dropdown-click').querySelectorAll('.has-submenu');

hasSubmenu.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // check if drop down was open
    var has = this.classList.contains('clicked');
    
    for(var i=0; i < this.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
      this.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove('clicked');
    }
    // note that after above loop no element have 'clicked' class
    // so if there was no 'clicked' class earlier add it
    if(!has){
      this.classList.add('clicked');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.basic-dropdown-click {
  display: table;
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li {
  width: 120px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:hover {
  background: #484848;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2), .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font: 0.9rem 'Roboto';
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2).clicked, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5).clicked {
  background: #484848;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2).clicked > ul, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5).clicked > ul {
  display: block;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #555;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:hover, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li:hover {
  background: #484848;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:not(:first-child), .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li a, .basic-dropdown-click > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font: 0.9rem 'Roboto';
}
.basic-dropdown-click > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 0.9rem 'Roboto';
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="basic-dropdown-click">
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu">Item 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <ul class="item-2-submenu">
          <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu">Item 5 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <ul class="item-5-submenu">
          <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```